# UIDevice.currentDevice.batteryLevel returns the same value every time I call it

Tags: ios

I'm trying to periodically query a device's battery level using `[[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel]`. The first time the code runs, I get an accurate value. However, subsequent calls appear to always return the same value, even when the device's battery level changes.

I understand this call only returns values in increments of 5%. That's not the issue here. Even when the battery level declines by 10 or 15 percent, [[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel] reports the same value.

`[UIDevice currentDevice].batteryState` does seem to be accurate. If I unplug the device, the value returned by that call changes.

The device I'm testing on is running iOS 6.

Comment: sounds like a bug in iOS 6 i.e. works when device plugged Vs not-plugged

Comment: Weird. Seems to be reporting accurately today.